# Error using mtimes

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to run this function like this: `calcSQNRA(0,4,6)` and I'm getting these errors:

> ??? Error using ==> mtimes Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in ==> calcSQNRA>@(x)x.^2*e.^(-x) at 6 f = @(x) x.^2 * e.^(-x);
>
> Error in ==> quadl at 70 y = feval(f,x,varargin{:}); y = y(:).';
>
> Error in ==> calcSQNRA at 7 x = 10 * log10(3 * 4^t *
>   quadl(f,xmin,xmax));

```
function [x] = calcSQNRA(xmin, xmax, N)

e = exp(1);
t = log2(N);

f = @(x) x.^2 * e.^(-x);
x = 10 * log10(3 * 4^t * quadl(f,xmin,xmax));
```

The function is trying to compute the SQNR of an exponential distribution (if I thought of it correctly), after a uniform quantization. Note that if I erase the `e.^(-x)` from f it actually produces a result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I kill 15 minutes debugging `quadl` and `feval` functions. And going so deep in this process I just think about this simple thing:

it just works if I set `.` in your `f` anonymous function this way:

```
f = @(x) x.^2 .* e.^(-x);
```

then 
`calcSQNRA(0,4,6)` give result: `22.1635`.

Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Exactly. `*` is a matrix multiplication, which is simply wrong and not possible in that place. The element-wise multiplication `.*` is needed here, as the function should work on each  `x` independently.

Comment: Thank you man! And to think  I had to put the dot on the powers before, as it didn't work.. silly error... Thank you both!